# NSDateFormatter returns unexpected String from date

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am using below code to create date string from Date

```
NSDate *localDate = [[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S'Z'"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:localDate];
```

And I am expecting a result like `"2016-01-06T01:14:18.8Z"`, it works as expected in most of the iPhones but in some phone above code generate date in different format like, `"2016-01-06T12:59:17.6 a.m.Z"`.

Anybody knows what would be the root cause of this behaviour

Comment: I got the issue. It was because of "Region" settings.

Comment: Why are you quoting the `Z` in the format? It's unlikely that is what you should be doing.